# Best Place to Remove NotificationCenter Observer in Swift Struct

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

Say we have a given Swift class.

```
class Test {
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( ... ) 
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

In a class, you can use the `deinit` lifecycle method to remove the `NotificationCenter` observer. In a struct, there is no `deinit` method. My question is therefore, where would someone remove the `NotificationCenter` observer in a struct? Or possibly, do we not have to remove the observer in a struct?

Comment: You could have the struct retain a reference to a class.  When `dealloc` is called on the class, you know the struct has been deallocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From iOS 9 and above, it's **not necessary** to remove `NotificationCenter` observers as they are **automatically removed**.

If you are concerned about observes stuck in memory anyway, you should call the removal from a class that is handling the struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't register a struct as an observer in the `NotificationCenter`. When you use the `addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)` method you have to pass the `Selector` as a parameter. The selector must be a function marked with `@objc` and you can use it only with classes.

When it comes to the classes you can unregister an observer in the `deinit` method as you mentioned in the question. However, you don't have to remove observers manually since iOS 9 because since this release `NSNotificationCenter` stores weak references to the observers. **Removing of the observers is not done automatically for you.**

According to the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_11.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016227-SW1).

> NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated. If the observer is able to be stored as a zeroing-weak reference the underlying storage stores the observer as a zeroing weak reference. Alternatively, if the object cannot be stored weakly (because it has a custom retain/release mechanism that would prevent the runtime from being able to store the object weakly) the object is stored as a non-weak zeroing reference. This means that observers are not required to un-register in their deallocation method.

Comment: Actually you can register a struct as an observer using closure instead of `@objc selector` method using  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver `func addObserver(forName name: NSNotification.Name?, 
          object obj: Any?, 
           queue: OperationQueue?, 
           using block: @escaping (Notification) -> Void) -> NSObjectProtocol `